# vanilla js capacitor simple routing doesn't work only in ios simulator

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, capacitor

It works fine on the web and Android but when the user is logged in location is not changing in the ios simulator. What could be the best approach to navigate in the vanilla js capacitor app?

I have tried;
`window.location.href` and `window.location.assign` methods.

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => { 
    if (!user && window.location.href.indexOf("register.html") == -1) {
        window.location.replace("../register.html");
    }

    if (user && window.location.href.indexOf("profile.html") == -1) {
        window.location.replace("../profile.html");
    }
}
```